# Coq/Ltac: is it possible to design a tactic that says the goal is proved when a decision procedure proves it, without the proof term?

Tags: coq, ltac

I am designing a Coq tactic that calls a decision procedure, which answers yes/no, without giving a proof term. When I get yes, I would like to say Ltac that the goal is proved.

Is there a way to do this? For instance, change the goal to `True`  and then use `exact I`?

I am using Ltac2, but I can use Ltac if it solves the problem.

I've heard about `Tactic.change_concl`, in Ltac, (https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.13.0/api/coq/Tactics/index.html) but I do not know if I can simply change the goal to True; and it is not available in Ltac2.

Comment: The question is: Do you want a well-founded proof? Or are you happy to trust your unverified decision procedure, which would mean your tactic just assumes the goal axiomatically..  There is precedent for either approach, depending on how foundational you want to be.

Comment: @JoJoModding For now, I'd be happy to trust an unverified procedure! Are there examples of this approach?

Comment: [Leapfrog](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~jnfoster/papers/leapfrog.pdf) implements an unverified approach, where an SMT solver is invoked and the result is added as an axiom, thereby trusting the SMT solver. [SMTCoq](https://smtcoq.github.io/) invokes SMT solvers but then reconstruct the proof found by the SMT solver in Coq, so that a wrong SMT solver result is caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically can't.  The point of Coq is that it guarantees proofs that have been checked, down to its own logical principles: a proof written in the language of the calculus of inductive constructions that is well-typed.  The tactics are only supposed to help you build such a proof, so anything that accepts the word of a different program as an *oracle* is outside the philosophy of the system.

Of course, there are workarounds.  For instance, you could collect all the results that are proved by an external tool in a database of some sort and then prove with Coq that you final statement is true, under the assumption that all the facts gathered in this database are true.  Ltac is not really the right tool for this.

I would suggest looking at the development of the tactics `bigenough` and `near` in the [math-comp eco system](https://github.com/math-comp/bigenough).